# XIB objects not loading onto screen

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I've setup a XIB custom file and added as a subview to the view controller, it is working well. Here is my initWithFrame and I'm trying to set some property values in the XIB but the objects do not seem to be showing on the view.

```
-(instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {

self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if(self) {
    [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass([self class]) owner:self options:nil];
    self.firstName.text = @"John";
    self.lastName.text = @"Michel";
    self.gender.text = @"Male";
}

return self;
}
```

I've checked in the debugger and the property labels are set so it's working on that front, but in the visual debugger the labels just don't show.

[image: visual]

Answer (score 0):

When you call initWithFrame it will not be loaded from XIB. If you want to load it from XIB. You should do this in view controller:

```
MyView *myView = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyView" owner:self options:nil];
```

If you want to access to the labels in your view controller then you should do this:

```
myView.firstName.text = @"John";
myView.lastName.text = @"Michel";
myView.gender.text = @"Male";
```

If you want to access them in the class. You should do it like this in your class:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    self.firstName.text = @"John";
    self.lastName.text = @"Michel";
    self.gender.text = @"Male";
}
```